# Why are page breaks inserted after sections?

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking

My problem is that page breaks and horizontal lines are inserted after sections, some chapters and the TOC. I have included all the code since I have no clue about which part of it is causing the problem or why.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{book}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[letterpaper, top=4cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=4cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\addto\captionsspanish{\renewcommand*\contentsname{TABLA DE CONTENIDOS}}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
%\input{./title.tex}
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\section*{MySection}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Preface}
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{MySection}
\section{MySection}
\section{MySection}
\subsection{subsect}
Lorem  ipsum  dolor  sit  amet,  consectetuer  adipiscing  
elit.   Etiam  lobortisfacilisis sem.  Nullam nec mi et 
neque pharetra sollicitudin.  Praesent imperdietmi nec ante. 
Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales
\chapter{Chapter2}
\appendix
\chapter{Reproducible Research}
\end{document}
```

[Here](https://www.overleaf.com/1862795gxzhvy#/4675154/) is a live document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lines are to separate the headers of your pages and the text. You can disable them by setting its width to 0:

```
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
```

It gets set by the `fancyhdr` package. They are by default disabled on "special" pages, like the first page of the TOC or of chapters, which use a different format.

The empty pages are inserted because every chapter should start as a right page. If you want to disable this (which you really shouldn't), use the `openany` option:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,openany]{book}
```

You shouldn't put `section` without a `chapter`, because that doesn't make sense (your first `section*`).

Comment: Thanks! This solves the problem with horizontal lines, but the page breaks are still there.

Comment: I've already added that, but please consider if you really want to remove them.